# Tooltip with ItemsControl doesn´t update on DataContext change

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, tooltip, itemscontrol

I got stuck with something that looked like simple mvvm binding.

I have a grid with a tooltip. DataContext of the Grid is changing and should update values in textBlock and the ItemsControl placed inside the tooltip. Problem is that the list inside the tooltip doesn't update. Just for test I added the same ItemsControl below the textblock. This list updates without problems. Here is simplified code that contains only what's necessary (I think so).

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedRouting}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionDescription}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoutingActionList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleActionTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ActionToolTipStyle}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoutingActionList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleActionTemplate}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

The question is: Why first ItemsControl (the one in StackPanel) updates when Main Grid DataContext is changed and the second ItemsControl Inside the ToolTip doesn't. Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `answer` for this question, may be this is what you want - [WPF Tooltip does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645370/wpf-tooltip-does-not-update)

Additionally in case you want to set tooltip within tooltip you can set the dataContext of your tooltip and it should work then -

```
 <Grid.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding SelectedRouting}" Style="{StaticResource ActionToolTipStyle}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoutingActionList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleActionTemplate}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </Grid.ToolTip>
```

Since the tooltip does not belong to the visual tree of your Control, hence changes are not get propagated to it. So, by setting the dataContext for your tooltip, you make it notifiable for PropertyChanges in Datacontext.

Comment: Solution you wrote gives in VS output : Cannot find element that provides DataContext...

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that WPF reads ToolTips as part of a different layer in WPF, so when the PropertyChange event gets called, it only gets triggered on the main layer

Try either specifying the DataContext for your ToolTip object so it gets alerted of PropertyChange notifications, or try removing it altogether

```
<Grid.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip DataContext={Binding RoutingActionList}" Style="{StaticResource ActionToolTipStyle}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleActionTemplate}"/>
    </ToolTip>
</Grid.ToolTip>
```

Or

```
<Grid.ToolTip>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SingleActionTemplate}"/>
</Grid.ToolTip>
```

Comment: Your first sugestion gives in VS output same as in RV1987 answer Cannot find element that provides DataContext. Second try is almost ok. Rest in next post

Answer (score 0):

Solution was in the link provided by RV1987. There cannot be `<ToolTip>` tag inside the `<Grid.ToolTip>` and it solves the problem I asked about.
Anyway there is still a minor problem. Removing the  tag removes also the possibility of assigning style to ToolTip. Whatever you put inside the tooltip, there is a default border visible. Assigning style to Tooltip I had i.e. the nice dark background. Now it's gone :( :(   Any ideas about that?