# How to set the ToolTip of WPF ComboBox based on selected value?

Tags: wpf, combobox, triggers, tooltip, selectedvalue

I have a `ComboBox` in my WPF application. Using below code I can set the `ToolTip` as selected value:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

But if I need to set a separate value for `ToolTip` based on `ComboBox` selection, the following code is not working:

```
<controls:ComboBoxEx.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource basicStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="DAW">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="abc"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="generic">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="def"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</controls:ComboBoxEx.Style>
```

Comment: What is your ComboBox bound to? A list of strings? Out of interest, try using SelectedItem rather than SelectedValue.

Comment: i tried both of them :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you are using a `Style` you should not have to use a `DataTrigger` or `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` to access `SelectedValue`, you should be able to access via a `Trigger` using the `Property`

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedValue"  Value="DAW">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="abc"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="generic">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="def"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried this...but not working... If I put the following setter as default <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>..it guives me the correct values DAW and generic when ever i select them...but inside the <trigger> it is not working.

Comment: Do you have `SelectedvaluePath` set on your `ComboBox`

Comment: What data type is in the combobox, can you post your ComboBox xaml, and a example of your collection.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I have figured it out ...instead of using data triggger with selected value..i used data trigger with original model object...now it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bind the tooltip to the display property of the selected item in this case i have property name display, if you have declarative ComboBox items then that would be

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content,ElementName=cmbbox_years}"
```

Else for custom object below code will work

```
<ComboBox 
  Name="cmbbox_years" 
  DisplayMemberPath="display" 
  SelectedValuePath="value"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Years}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding YearSelectedItem}" 
  ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.display,ElementName=cmbbox_years}"/>
```

Comment: This will work for a single pass, but it won't update the ToolTip with subsequent viewmodel changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313801/271200